# An error with CMAKE and NDK on Android when opening a pre-existing github library. (Using Windows 10)

Tags: android, c++, c, cmake, android-ndk

So as mentioned, I am trying to open a github zip. It uses NDK and CMAKE. Now the main issue is I am getting these two errors:

[image: Error Image]
Incomplete line:

```
Error while executing 'C:\sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe' with arguments {-HE:\SpeedTest\iperf3-android-master\app -BE:\SpeedTest\iperf3-android-master\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\release\armeabi -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi -DANDROID_NDK=C:\sdk\ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=E:\SpeedTest\iperf3-android-master\app\build\intermediates\cmake\release\obj\armeabi -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\ninja.exe -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\sdk\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=18 -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=-I./src/ -IE:\SpeedTest\iperf3-android-master\app -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=}
```

I installed MinGW (C drive itself) and added packages:

1. mingw32-gcc (all 5 classes)
2. mingw-gcc-g++ (all 4 classes).

It didn't work.

Note my SDK folder is also in C drive which contains ndk & cmake (downloaded via SDK Manager).

In my `CMakeLists.txt` I also manually changed the path to:

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER C:/MinGW/bin/gcc)
set(CMAKE_C++_COMPILER C:/MinGW/bin/g++)
```

This is the library I am trying to execute:

https://github.com/t-higuchi/iperf3-android/tree/master/app

After that I used the standard SDK Manager to add NDK, CMake and LLDB.
Though the library has another CMakeLists.txt. But its rather blank. If I am to make changes then how do I do. Which terminal window to give CMake commands (if any). I am new to NDK. Please check out the library.

Any help?

Comment: It is difficult to say anything from given image: CMake cannot find compilers, but a reason is absent on the image. Instead, provide **textual representation of the errors**. When use toolchain, it is too late to set compiler in the `CMakeLists.txt`. You need to pass variables to cmake itself (via `-D` option). Also, you use incorrect variable for C++ compiler. Correct one is shown in the error message.

Comment: Let me add the library to give a better picture.
After that I used the standard SDK Manager to add NDK, CMake and LLDB.
Though the library has another CMakeLists.txt. But its rather blank. I am new to NDK. Please check out the library. Thanks!